# How do I tell what has changed in an EF Core NuGet update?

Tags: entity-framework-core

Is there a way I can tell what the bug fixes (or new features) are in a release of the various Entity Framework Core NuGet packages?

Like today, when I saw that the 3 packages I use went from version 6.0.7 to 6.0.8. I'm sure there are some bug fixes but what are they?  There does not seem to be a list. I've been all over the github pages, tried the readme, the milestones, followed all the links. It seems like it should be easy but I can never find it.

Do they actually compile a list somewhere of what is in a release that I am missing?

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/releases

Comment: Thank you!  I thought I had clicked all over the github project page looking for exactly that.  Feel silly for not having found that.  I wish Visual Studio would put *that* (or something like it) into the "Manage NuGet Packages" windows  when I'm updating.  They give me all sorts of links there except the one I wanted.